# Multiple Table Report in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have my question posted in [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/566704/design-report-with-multiple-table-structure.html).
All tables except grading system are linked. I have 4 data tables for that report

1. Student-Marksheet
2. Student-Academic Skill
3. Student-Personal Skill
4. Grading System

First 3 tables have common column named AdmissionNo
On each page I need to show particular student marksheet, academic skill and personal skill

I have used sub-report for academic and personal skill but this shows all records instead of particular page on each page

Answer (score 0):

Right-click each subreport and use the option to change subreport link to AdmissionNo. Use the options in that dialog to ensure the subreport records are restricted to those with a matching AdmissionNo.

Make sure each subreport contains only the 2 tables it needs (e.g. Grading + Student-Academic Skill) to avoid record inflation.